# Removing rounding errors in image rotation in c

Tags: c, image, rotation

Long time lurker... first time asker...

I have a routine that takes an image stored in an array {x, y, colour} and rotates it. If the angle of rotation is anything other than a multiple of 90, there are rounding errors that leave pixels empty. Does anyone out there have either a better rotation solution, or alternatively a way to catch the misplaced pixels?

```
void 
PlaceGraphicRot(unsigned int graphic[][3], int xcent, int ycent, int intangle) {
    int i = 0;
    double xorig, yorig, xdraw, ydraw;
    double rotangle = (3.14159265358979323846 * intangle) / 180; // convert provided integer angle to radians
    do {
        xorig = graphic[i][0];
    yorig = graphic[i][1];
        xdraw = (cos(rotangle) * (xorig - xcent) - sin(rotangle) * (yorig - ycent) + xcent);
        ydraw = (sin(rotangle) * (xorig - xcent) + cos(rotangle) * (yorig - ycent) + ycent);
        //place pixel
        TFT_DrawPixel(round(xdraw), round(ydraw), RGBDown(graphic[i][2]));
        i++;
    } while (graphic[i][0] != 999); //delimiter to indicate end of image
}
```

Many thanks in advance...
Rob

Answer (score 1):

The way to avoid having gaps in between valid pixels is to work backwards. Rather than taking each pixel in the source image and moving it to its place in the destination image by rotating the pixel to a new position, you should iterate through each pixel in the destination image and figure out which pixel in the source image it corresponds to.

To do this you just need to go through each pixel `(xdraw,ydraw)` in the destination image and apply the **inverse** rotation to get the corresponding pixel `(xorig,yorig)` in the source image.

Luckily, the inverse of a rotation matrix is really easy: it's just the transpose of the matrix. So the only change to your calculations is to change the sign of `sin(rotangle)` in both equations (and, of course, swap `*orig` with `*draw`):

```
xorig = ( cos(rotangle) * (xdraw - xcent) + sin(rotangle) * (ydraw - ycent) + xcent);
yorig = (-sin(rotangle) * (xdraw - xcent) + cos(rotangle) * (ydraw - ycent) + ycent);
         ^---- sign changes here ---------^
```

From there, assuming `(xorig,yorig)` is within the range of the original image, you can take the nearest pixel, or interpolate the value from neighbors.

You'll need to decide what you want to do if the pixel is out of range. There will always be some missing pixels in the corners unless you crop the destination image (or your image is square and you're only rotating by 90° multiples). You can make the pixels black, or white, or whatever is right for your application.

Comment: +1 Just the approach I would have used, except maybe rounding the answer with `xorg = round(( cos(rotangle) ...);`

Comment: @chux The reason I didn't round it was to allow for interpolation, if desired. But yes, if you're going to use nearest-neighbor you would certainly want to round in the same statement.

Comment: Interpolation and rounding can be used together.  The rounding is important when the value before integer truncation is something.99999999 and user hopes for something+1.  IAC - it is a small detail.  Your "to work backwards" is the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

First, many thanks for the responses. The guidance helped me reach an ultimate solution.

Background: My original issue with attempting to work backwards is the method I was using to store my image. I was only storing pixels that were not the same as the background to save on space. This also caused an issue with bilinear interpolation. I did attempt 2501's solution, however the image quality was not sufficient.

In the end, I chose to restore my image including the background pixels to achieve a squared image. I then used a great article (no really... well written and great examples) on bilinear interpolation from http://polymathprogrammer.com/2008/10/06/image-rotation-with-bilinear-interpolation/ and adapted if for my needs.

My resulting function, while MUCH bigger, provides a very clear image on rotation:

```
void
PlaceGraphicRot(unsigned int graphic[24][24], int xoffset, int yoffset, int intangle) {
    intangle += 90; // get rid of strange rotation
    double PI = 3.14159265358979323846;
    const int cnSizeBuffer = 2;
    // rotating clockwise, so it's negative relative to Cartesian quadrants
    const double cnAngle = -(intangle * PI) /180;
    // calculated indices in Cartesian coordinates
    int x, y;
    double fDistance, fPolarAngle;
    // for use in neighbouring indices in Cartesian coordinates
    int iFloorX, iCeilingX, iFloorY, iCeilingY;
    // calculated indices in Cartesian coordinates with trailing decimals
    double fTrueX, fTrueY;
    // for interpolation
    double fDeltaX, fDeltaY;
    // pixel colours
    int clrTopLeft, clrTopRight, clrBottomLeft, clrBottomRight;
    // interpolated "top" pixels
    double fTopRed, fTopGreen, fTopBlue;
    // interpolated "bottom" pixels
    double fBottomRed, fBottomGreen, fBottomBlue;
    // final interpolated colour components
    int iRed, iGreen, iBlue;
    int iCentreX, iCentreY;
    int iDestCentre;
    int iWidth, iHeight;
    int iDiagonal;
    iWidth = 24;
    iHeight = 24;
    iDiagonal = (int) (ceil(sqrt((double) (iWidth * iWidth + iHeight * iHeight)))) + cnSizeBuffer;
    iCentreX = iWidth / 2;
    iCentreY = iHeight / 2;
    iDestCentre = iDiagonal / 2;
    // assigning pixels of destination image from source image
    // with bilinear interpolation
    for (int i = 0; i < iDiagonal; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < iDiagonal; ++j) {
            // convert raster to Cartesian
            x = j - iDestCentre;
            y = iDestCentre - i;

            // convert Cartesian to polar
            fDistance = sqrt(x * x + y * y);
            fPolarAngle = 0.0;
            if (x == 0) {
                if (y == 0) {
                    // centre of image, no rotation needed
                    TFT_DrawPixel(j + xoffset, i + yoffset, RGBDown(graphic[iCentreX][iCentreY]));
                    continue;
                } else if (y < 0) {
                    fPolarAngle = 1.5 * PI;
                } else {
                    fPolarAngle = 0.5 * PI;
                }
            } else {
                fPolarAngle = atan2((double) y, (double) x);
            }

            // the crucial rotation part
            // "reverse" rotate, so minus instead of plus
            fPolarAngle -= cnAngle;

            // convert polar to Cartesian
            fTrueX = fDistance * cos(fPolarAngle);
            fTrueY = fDistance * sin(fPolarAngle);

            // convert Cartesian to raster
            fTrueX = fTrueX + (double) iCentreX;
            fTrueY = (double) iCentreY - fTrueY;

            iFloorX = (int) (floor(fTrueX));
            iFloorY = (int) (floor(fTrueY));
            iCeilingX = (int) (ceil(fTrueX));
            iCeilingY = (int) (ceil(fTrueY));

            // check bounds
            if (iFloorX < 0 || iCeilingX < 0 || iFloorX >= iWidth || iCeilingX >= iWidth || iFloorY < 0 || iCeilingY < 0 || iFloorY >= iHeight || iCeilingY >= iHeight) continue;

            fDeltaX = fTrueX - (double) iFloorX;
            fDeltaY = fTrueY - (double) iFloorY;

            clrTopLeft = graphic[iFloorX][iFloorY];
            clrTopRight = graphic[iCeilingX][iFloorY];
            clrBottomLeft = graphic[iFloorX][iCeilingY];
            clrBottomRight = graphic[iCeilingX][iCeilingY];

            // linearly interpolate horizontally between top neighbours
            fTopRed = (1 - fDeltaX) * (clrTopLeft & 0xFF0000 >> 16) + fDeltaX * (clrTopRight & 0xFF0000 >> 16);
            fTopGreen = (1 - fDeltaX) * (clrTopLeft & 0x00FF00 >> 8) + fDeltaX * (clrTopRight & 0x00FF00 >> 8);
            fTopBlue = (1 - fDeltaX) * (clrTopLeft & 0x0000FF) + fDeltaX * (clrTopRight & 0x0000FF);

            // linearly interpolate horizontally between bottom neighbours
            fBottomRed = (1 - fDeltaX) * (clrBottomLeft & 0xFF0000 >> 16) + fDeltaX * (clrBottomRight & 0xFF0000 >> 16);
            fBottomGreen = (1 - fDeltaX) * (clrBottomLeft & 0x00FF00 >> 8) + fDeltaX * (clrBottomRight & 0x00FF00 >> 8);
            fBottomBlue = (1 - fDeltaX) * (clrBottomLeft & 0x0000FF) + fDeltaX * (clrBottomRight & 0x0000FF);

            // linearly interpolate vertically between top and bottom interpolated results
            iRed = (int) (round((1 - fDeltaY) * fTopRed + fDeltaY * fBottomRed));
            iGreen = (int) (round((1 - fDeltaY) * fTopGreen + fDeltaY * fBottomGreen));
            iBlue = (int) (round((1 - fDeltaY) * fTopBlue + fDeltaY * fBottomBlue));

            // make sure colour values are valid
            if (iRed < 0) iRed = 0;
            if (iRed > 255) iRed = 255;
            if (iGreen < 0) iGreen = 0;
            if (iGreen > 255) iGreen = 255;
            if (iBlue < 0) iBlue = 0;
            if (iBlue > 255) iBlue = 255;

            TFT_DrawPixel(j + xoffset, i + yoffset, RGBDown((iRed << 16) + (iGreen << 8) + iBlue));
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks again for the assistance!